# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT in request module

Tags: node.js, request

I have an error, my bot in node.js returns `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` error, after get request to my page. I don't know where is the error, therefore, I need help. This is my code:

```
var request = require('request');

function update() {
    request.get('http://gamesters.eu/api/tv/v1.php?apikey=xxx&action=getStatus', function (error, response, body) {
        if(error) throw error;
        var obj = body;

        console.log(body);
    });
}

update();
setInterval(function() {
    update();
}, 1500);
```

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` means your request is timing out because server is not responding

Comment: Yes, the server is not responding. Problem solved.